# How can I host a file server on the web?

Tags: webserver, fileserver

I would like to be able to host my own file server so I can acess my files whereever I am. I tried countless tutorials but none worked in the end. The only thing that works is acessing my files on my local network.

Comment: If it only works on your local network, the problem is probably that you can't reach the server from outside the network. Have you tried port forwarding?

Comment: @FredrickReynolds Port Forwarding is the issue. Either I'm doing the settings wrong on my router either there is another technical issue